Typorm with op-sqlite crash my app(react native)
When I started the app, my app crashed during init sqlite databases, that worked well before we decided to upgrade to a different package of our project. It feels like typeorm adaptor not working well, so we don't see where is the problem.
Our driver that worked before upgrade:
  const connection = {
    executeSql: (
      sql: string,
      params: any[] | undefined,
      ok: (res: QuickSQLite.QueryResult) => void,
      fail: (msg: string) => void
    ) => {
      try {
        let response =  database.execute(
          sql,
          params
        );
        enhanceQueryResult(response);
        ok(response);
      } catch (e) {
        fail(e);
      }
    },
    transaction: (
      fn: (tx: QuickSQLite.Transaction) => Promise<void>
    ): Promise<void> => {
      return database.transaction(fn);
    },
    close: (ok: any, fail: any) => {
      try {
        database.close();
        ok();
      } catch (e) {
        fail(e);
      }
    },
    attach: (
      dbNameToAttach: string,
      alias: string,
      location: string | undefined,
      callback: () => void
    ) => {
      database.attach(options.name, dbNameToAttach, alias, location);

      callback();
    },
    detach: (alias: any, callback: () => void) => {
      database.detach(options.name, alias);

      callback();
    },
  };

  ok(connection);

  return connection;
} catch (e) {
  fail(e);
}

},
};](https://stackoverflow.com)
A different version of the package depends on db
react-native": 0.74.2
@op-engineering/op-sqlite": ^6.0.7
typeorm": "^0.3.20
